# Can I prevent users with a too-old OS version from downloading my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I currently have an app in the app store that works for iPhone users running iOS version 3.0 or newer. My next version of the app is going to use ARC, so it will only work for users running iOS version 4.0 or newer.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054963/can-i-prevent-an-iphone-os-3-x-app-from-running-on-2-x-os), the users will be able to download the newer version, but it just won't run when they try to run it.

Is there any way to prevent users who can't run the app from even downloading it from the AppStore?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this recently, but in February 2011, and iOS 4.x, I had users who couldn't download my app as there device wasn't running the required version of iOS.

They received a nice explanation message on their device, courtesy of the App Store app, when trying to download the app directly to their device.

I'd be very surprised if this wasn't still the case.

So, set the deployment target in your target build settings, and let the App Store / iTunes take care of who can install it.

That was for new installs, and it be different for updates (rather than new installs) but again I'd be surprised if this wasn't handled by Apple for the sake of a better user experience.

**UPDATE**

I dug out my old iPhone 3 which reached the end of the road at 4.2.1 and resynced it with iTunes - the latest apps that require 4.3 etc are ignored, and are not overwritten with incompatible versions, as I would expect.

I also tried to update my own app (I'm a developer), requiring 4.3 and above, from the store via the device itself, and got a polite pop-up alert saying the app requires iOS 4.3 and above, again just as I'd expect.

The app was previously compatible with < 4.3, and somewhere along the line I bumped up the minimum iOS version requirement, so it is definitely possible.

So, you should just set your updated app's 'deployment target' version appropriately, and it will only be updated on compatible devices.

Comment: Was your app a new one, or an old one for which you upgraded the minimum supported OS version? Also are you talking about new users who could not download your app, or users who already have your app and want to download it again?

Comment: In this case, it was new users who could not download the app as their iPhone iOS version was below the 'deployment target'. The deployment target of the app hadn't changed.

Comment: If your app is already in the app store and supports version 3.0 of iOS, then apple will not validate newer updates that don't support that version. This is what OP is trying to do.

Comment: My previous comment is wrong. We can change the target build to newer versions as you said, but we can't upgrade device capabilities according to this link: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/uirequireddevicecapabilities-cannot-be-changed-in-app-updates/

Answer (score 0):

No.  A new higher minimum Deployment target will prevent a user from installing an app on a device with a lower OS version, but will not prevent them from downloading the app using iTunes on their Mac or PC, even though they can't install the update once downloaded.