# iPhone : how to push a new version not compatible with previously supported OSv3.2

Tags: iphone, ios5

I a trying to publish a new version of an app, I started this new version from scratch and now, when I am trying to push it to apple I got an error saying to me that i must support previously supported iOS version.

I am working on an iOS 5 SDK and the previous app was for iOS 3.2+ which is really amazingly hard to support with SDK 5 (amrv6 and other crazy stuff).

So I want to publish this app for iOS 5 only : how can I handle this?

**EDIT :** after more searches referinf from : 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1623/_index.html

> Developers who wish to issue updates, but remove device support, have two choices:
>
> - Fix their app so that it can work on the devices they originally set
>     out to support. See Supporting All Devices for details.
> - Remove their
>     app from the store, and upload the new app with a different bundle ID.
>     See Replacing Your App in the Store for details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I prevent users with a too-old OS version from downloading my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319594/can-i-prevent-users-with-a-too-old-os-version-from-downloading-my-app)

Comment: People in the linked question appear to have had a different experience - can you give more details about the errors in your case?

Comment: Hi, When I try to validate the app, I got this error "The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this application from running on devices that were supported by previous versions"

Comment: Well, that's a different question. What is in the capabilities section, or do you only have an iOS version in there?

Comment: I've corrected all those incrimined sections exept one : the SDK : i only have the coice for the SDK 5...

Answer (score 0):

Don't set it in the device capabilities, just set the minimum target version in your build settings and you should be fine.